# How can I use FontAwesome Font Icons without uploading it to project?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, blogger

I have a blog. Now I want to use a font icon for Menu bar for good quality.

But I can't upload it to blogger as there's no option. So is there any way to use it without uploading it to blogger?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=fontawesome+cdn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a CDN  and link it in your project like this

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: This is I'm using already. But it renders little slow. First a square is rendered then the original icon.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Could you please tell the difference between font-awesome.css and font-awesome.min.css? I saw them on offline downloaded folder.

Comment: one is the regular CSS file the other is the same file but minified (compressed) for performance/speed things (that's the `.min` file)

Comment: Can I use any of them if I want to try offline? I've downloaded the files and fonts from FontAwesome official link.

Comment: yes ofc you can, I recommend using the `min` one since you are not touching that file

Comment: Thank you. I'll try in a few minutes and will let you know if it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

As answered you can use fontawesome cdn or if you want to further optimize, you can choose specific icons and load a css file.

you can use http://fontello.com/ or https://icomoon.io which are awesome tools for this.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Could you please tell the difference between font-awesome.css and font-awesome.min.css? I saw them on offline downloaded folder. I want to try it for learning on Desktop.

Comment: font-awesome.min.css is the minified version of font-awesome.css. It is suggested to use minified version for any library we use for our website, so that we can improve page load

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I couldn't select your answer. All I could do is make -1 to 0.

Comment: I guess you can uncheck the other answers and check another which helps you situation more. :)

Comment: For now, it's done. I've lot of questions that I'll ask. You can try them :)